# Mixing MVC and API in the same controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC project, when I deploy and try with an another person, the website freeze and timeout.

When we started the project, we created MVC controller and everything worked fine. Then we needed to have some data sources for the front, and we include "API" (note the quotes) methods in the same controller of the MVC. And then problems start to emerge.

Recently we deployed the project in production, I asked someone to help me test and find bugs. We connect and when we load the home page, the JS API calls timeout. First I suspected the service calls that the web backend do, but after some debugging, it's not that.

The shaddy thing is in local (and alone), everything works flawlessly.
So I needed to go deeper in the test, I asked the other tester to load the home as the same time with me, on the other hand I fire up Postman to call an "API" endpoint of the website. The view rendered perfectly and the JS call the API and go timeout 15 sec later and in Postman, the request never find a response.

Conclusion and question time, what I discovered is API calls seems blocked when when multiple connections use the controller. After few google searches, I found that in ASP.NET Core 2.x, MVC and API don't extend the same base code, MVC extends Controller because it supports Views and API extends ControllerBase which is the same as Controller without Views support. And many people says that MVC and API controllers has to be 2 different controllers.

But, that does not answer my base problem, why API calls in MVC controller break when there are more than 1 user using the website ? And why MVC controller can't handle API endpoints ? Is this because of the views ?

Hope I made my mind clear because it is something I'd like to have an answer beside apply what people (and documentation I think) says.

Edit : here a sample of what it is now

```cs
public FooController : Controller 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        return StatusCode(200, new { value = 1 });
    }
}
```

Index rendered correctly and the call https://example.com/Foo/GetData timeout or never find a response when more than 1 user use the website.

Route configuration :

```cs
applicationBuilder.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "cultureRoute",
        template: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Logon", action = "Index" },
        constraints: new
        {
            culture = new RegexRouteConstraint("^[a-z]{2}(?:-[A-Z]{2})?$")
        });

        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "/{controller=Logon}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

1 day later, I found the origin of the problem, we use SignalR to sync data accross users, for a certain unknown reason, when I disable SignalR everything works at any user connected. So, how SignalR can block all requests to the API at a certain point ?

Comment: "why API calls in MVC controller break when there are more than 1 user using the website": My best guess is there's a bug in your controller. Please include the code that reproduces the same issue.

Comment: 1. Could please elaborate on what is "broken"? Is there any error you get?  2. Did you configure the routes ?

Comment: "Broken" is I send the request and it timeout or never find a response. And yes, I configured the routes which is in the startup class.

Comment: Could you please also include the routes configuration in the startup ?

Comment: Actually, your code runs fine for me. This makes me believe there must be a bug in your code not shown here. If you can't provide a way that reproduces, please check logs by the "API" method that runs in production to make sure the request has been processed correctly by Controller instead of other middlewares.

Comment: Actually, when the JS makes the call, the back never receive the request, so no error is raised. And I'm 100% sure that the URL call is correct. But the Index return correctly the view when called. And the only middlewares I have is for the culture and custom user authentication.

Comment: I believe the url is correct. However, to narrow down the issues, could you please make sure your `GetData()` method works correctly in production? Let's say it hangs up and never returns (e.g. dead lock), you'll probably get a timeout

Comment: I'm sure that ```GetData()``` works correctly, when I'm alone in the production, everything works fine, the problem occurs when someone else wants to use at the same time the website. And suddently the JS call to ```GetData()``` will never be reached.

Comment: "occurs when someone else wants to use at the same time": This statement indicates it is not working correctly. As I said before,  you're probably experiencing a dead lock caused by concurrency, thus you get a timeout.  However, since your above sample code doesn't reproduce at all, we can't help you at present. 1. Please make sure your sample code can reproduce the same issue.  2. Please check out the **log**.

Comment: We found what blocked the request, it was SignalR, when we desactivate it, everything worked, however, we didn't found a fix for this. And no log was written because the AJAX request didn't even reached the API and because of it, the AJAX request timed out.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. It was not SignalR that blocked the request but the bug in your code.

Comment: There is no bug in the code, we tested the code hundreds times in different configurations and the code works perfectly and write log if there an error. Here, the code isn't even called by the front because the request is blocked somewhere and thus the AJAX request went timeout. When we disable SignalR, the API calls works perfectly, we tested with 3 users connected at the same time, reload at the same time and no bug. SignalR by an unknown reason block the API calls at some point.